# Alignment of padded floats in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a small problem in having my figure legend aligned correctly. My legend entries are two parameters from my simulations which should be horizontally aligned. I have tried using padding and `format()`, but in the first legend entry, the alignment is off:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), label="snr: {: <6.1f}N: {}".format(float("inf"), 1))
ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), label="snr: {: <6.1f}N: {}".format(float("0.10000"), 1))
ax.plot(np.random.rand(100), label="snr: {: <6.1f}N: {}".format(float("1.00000"), 1))

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("image.png")
```

Output (added red line to highlight alignment):

[image]

I would have thought that padding to 6 characters would align the `N` as is the case when I do

```
print("snr: {: <6.1f}N: {}".format(float("inf"), 1))
print("snr: {: <6.1f}N: {}".format(float("0.10000"), 1))
print("snr: {: <6.1f}N: {}".format(float("1.00000"), 1))
```

Output:

```
snr: inf   N: 1
snr: 0.1   N: 1
snr: 1.0   N: 1
```

This is with `matplotlib` version 3.3.2

Comment: Your terminal uses a monospaced font, matplotlib does not (by default).

Comment: `ax.legend(..., prop={"family": "monospace"})`